# Order initial values in RethinkDB changefeed (nested query)

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

How can I get the initial values of a nested-query changefeed ordered?

I my case I have a table with Twitter users - and each user has a field containing several tags.
Now I want to subscribe to all the Tweets of users, that are tagged by 'hello' AND 'world', and apply some additional filtering (e.g. no retweets).

To show the recent Tweets, they must be ordered.

This is my current try, which works fine (without ordering):

```
r.table('users')
   .filter(user => {
       return user('tags')('text').contains(r.args(['hello', 'world']));
    })
    .getField('id_str')
    .coerceTo('array')
    .do(users => {
          return r.db('twitterdb').table('tweets').getAll(r.args(users), {index: 'user_id'})
        })
    .filter(tweet => {
          return tweet.hasFields('retweeted_status').not();
    })
    .changes({includeInitial: true})
    .limit(5)
```

According to the docs:

- **orderBy must be used with indexes**. orderBy requires limit; neither
  command works by itself. orderBy must be used with a secondary index
  or the primary index; it cannot be used with an unindexed field.
  https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/
- **An orderBy command that uses a secondary index cannot be chained
  after getAll**. You can only chain it after a table command. However,
  you can chain orderBy after a between command provided it uses the
  same index. https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/